# how to pass variables in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am cleaning up a code, but I came across this problem. for example.
how can I get the variable from function b to a?

```
function a()
{
    var a = 0;
    function b(a);
    if( a == 1){
        function c;
    }
}
function b{
    a = 1
}
```

thannk you

Comment: Code is riddled with syntax issues...

Comment: If you want to share a variable between functions you can declare it outside of any function. Alternately, you can pass it as a parameter.

Comment: sorry for that, I wasn't paying attention. But do you get it or should I rewrite it?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript does not have pass-by-reference, so your options for having a function modify a variable are:

1. Have it return the new value, and assign back to the variable
2. Pass it an array reference and have it modify one of the entries in the array
3. Pass it an object reference and have it modify a property on the object
4. Use a variable declared in the scope containing both functions; then they both close over it, and share it — but don't use globals or near-globals unnecessarily

The code in the question has too many issues for me to understand it, but if the goal is to have function `b` *modify* variable `a` within function `a`, your best bet is #1:

```js
function a() {
  var a = 1;
  a = b(a);
  snippet.log(a); // 2
}
function b(arg) {
  return arg * 2;
}

a();
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested code, but maybe somthing similar to this:

```
function a(randomname)
{
    var variable = randomname
    alert(variable);  //Popup message box with passed variable "Hello".
    var a = 0;
    function b(a);
    if( a == 1){
        function c;
    }
}
function b{
    var value = "Hello"
    a(value);   //Pass variables like this. Go to function "A" and pass "value".

}
```